# Making a Vertically Aligned Div More than 100% If Needed

Tags: css, height, vertical-alignment

I am vertically aligning a div using Michał Czernow's technique posted on CSS Tricks:

**HTML**

```html
 <div class="block">
    <div class="centered">
        Unknown stuff to be centered.
    </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
 /* This parent can be any width and height */
 .block {
   text-align: center;
 }

 /* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
 .block:before {
   content: '';
  display: inline-block;
   height: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
 }

 /* The element to be centered, can
    also be of any width and height */ 
 .centered {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 300px;
 }
```

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

This method works perfectly, however, if I have content that exceeds the height of the browser window, the content breaks outside of its div.

My question is this. Is there a way to keep height: 100%, but make height: auto for divs that exceed the browser height (if possible without js)?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

`min-height:100%`? Seems like a simple solution unless I'm missing something.